# Subdomain URL not loading properly in android webView

Tags: javascript, android, css, webview, opencart

I'm trying to load [This Website](http://www.opensourcecart.com/index.php?route=mobile_app/home) that is designed like its a mobile app have a top bar like Actionbar and its actionbar contain some items and a searchbar.
The leftmost and rightmost items open a layout like `Navigation Drawer` in android.
When I run this app with `webView` what I see in app is drawer layouts are opened by default, left drawer layout is at the top then right drawer below it and main page is at the end of it.
It seems like CSS in not loading properly or some of the javascript too.
In the browser when I try with mobile view at any `width` & `height` its working well.
So I wanna know why its not working well in android?
Here is my code to load website in `webVeiw` complete mainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String link = "http://www.opensourcecart.com/index.php?route=mobile_app/home";
    String urlLink = "http://www.opencartarabic.com";
    Context context;
    private WebView mWebview;
    private ProgressDialog progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.context = this;

        // Programmatically show fullscreen
//        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
//        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
//                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Progress Dialog", "Loading...");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(myWebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
//        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        mWebview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            // chromium, enable hardware acceleration
            mWebview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else {
            // older android version, disable hardware acceleration
            mWebview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }
            }
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
//                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + description);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                alertDialog.setMessage(description);
                alertDialog.setButton(BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
        mWebview.loadUrl(link);
    }
}
```

I also have tried with these methods

```
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

But its the same. The code is working well for all website urls except this one

```
 http://www.opensourcecart.com/index.php?route=mobile_app/home
```

Maybe its because its a subdomain (not sure). Please guide me to the right direction.
Onclick of searchbar is also not working in android app.

**Edit:** opening this url in android browser also working fine.

Comment: try this https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView

Comment: Ok, let me try.

Comment: @shahzainali Thanks it works like a charm now :)

Comment: Good, Welcome :)